# async/await timeout after fadeout when fadein is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I've this piece of code which basically does:
 --When the ajax (promise) is executed:
    -Fadeout, and when the fadeout finished:
      --Fade in:

```
async function loadForm (data) {

   let promiseForm = pForm(data);
   await promiseForm.then(function(data) {

          setTimeout(function () {

            $container.fadeOut(function() {
                $container.append(msg);
                $container.fadeIn();
            });

          }, 800);
    });

}
```

But now i need handle then all this is done

I've tried this code but didn't worked because the Jquery selector is executed before the fadeout callback, so $container html hasn't been appended yet.

```
async function loadForm (data) {

 let promiseForm = pForm(data);
 await promiseForm.then(function(data) {

        setTimeout(function () {

          $container.fadeOut(function() {
              $container.append(msg);
              $container.fadeIn();
          });

        }, 800);

  });

}
async function checkActiveForm() {

  let promiseActiveForm = pCheckActiveForm
  await promiseActiveForm.then((json) => {

          loadForm(data).then(function() {
              $(document).find("#"+logEvento.id).prop('checked',true); 
              //This element is created on the $container.append(msg) of "A" function
          });
  });

}
```

---

---

## SOLVED:

```
async function loadForm (data) {

   let promiseForm = pForm(data);
   var msg ;
   await promiseForm.then(function(data) {
       msg = response;
    });

    await new Promise(res => {
       setTimeout(function () {

          $container.fadeOut(function() {
             $container.append(msg);
             $container.fadeIn();

             res();
          });

        }, 800);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript isn't aware that the setTimeout is asynchronous, and you aren't telling it in any way. You should tell that in the `setTimeout` callback the flow is synced again.

Instead, you are launching a timeout and going ahead (and no matter if it's inside a promise!).

Furthermore, your await is useless, because you are waiting two promises to solve, but you aren't doing anything after that you waited.

Maybe you meant something like this:

```
await promiseForm; // Wait the first promise
await new Promise (res => { // Wait the timeout
      setTimeout(function () {
        $container.fadeOut(function() {
            $container.append(msg);
            $container.fadeIn();
            res();
        });
      }, 800);
});
// Do something after that everything happened
```

PS. Are the two promises needed to be executed in sequence? Can't you parallelise them (getting a performance improvement)?

Maybe you could use `Promise.all`

Comment: I couldn't use `Promise.all` because the content of the `$container.append(msg)` depends on the response of promiseForm, i'm figuring out how to implement the code above and will be giving my answer! Thanks!

Comment: Solved! Thank you! However, if the `setTimeout` was inside the `await promiseForm.then();`, javascript doesn't await both the promise and the `.then();` callback to finisfh the execution?